# DAX Combine two calculate formulas into one

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a single measure that counts the number of rows that meet a certain criteria. The measure is currently made up to calculate functions because a number of rows needs to be excluded from the first count of rows:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Calls'), FILTER('Calls', 
   ('Calls'[Status] = "Served") &&
   'Calls'[exclude] = "N" &&
   ('Calls'[Agent] <> 1 ||
   ('Calls'[Registered] = "Y" && ('Calls'[Type] = "NA" || 'Calls'[Type] = "SO")
)
))
-
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Calls'), FILTER('Calls', 
   ('Calls'[Status] = "Served") &&
   'Calls'[exclude] = "N" &&
   'Calls'[Agent] = 1 && 
   CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 1) || CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 2) || CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 3) || CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 4))
))
```

It all works as expected but the formula is problematic when it comes to needing to assess the average call times for the same results. This means that I need to actually combine the two into ONE calculate formula and that's where I'm stuck due to the complex combinations of ands and ors which make it so that I don't end up with expected results.

I've tried this:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Calls'), FILTER('Calls', 
   ('Calls'[Status] = "Served") &&
   'Calls'[exclude] = "N" &&
   ('Calls'[Agent] <> 1 ||
   ('Calls'[Registered] = "Y" && ('Calls'[Type] = "NA" || 'Calls'[Type] = "SO") 
) &&
  ('Calls'[Agent] = 1 && 
   NOT(CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 1)) || NOT(CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 2)) || NOT(CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 3)) || NOT(CONTAINSSTRING('Calls'[Type], 4)))
))
```

But this doesn't return the expected results.

Can someone help we with the correct combination of ands and ors to get this formula into one calculate formula please?